# Conversion From String " " to Type Integer is not valid

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, tostring

I know this has been ask already I tried everything but none work for me.
Please help this is my first post..

My Code  `

```
    Dim MyDataRow As DataRow = MyDataTbl.Rows(0)
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strState As String

    strName = MyDataRow("ContactName")
    strState = MyDataRow("State")
    NameTxt.Text = strName.ToString
    StateTxt.Text = strState.ToString

    If MyDataTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        NameTxt.Text = " "
        StateTxt.Text = " "
        Exit Sub
    End If


    NameTxt.Text = MyDataTbl.Rows("ContactName").ToString() "ERROR HERE"
    StateTxt.Text = MyDataTbl.Rows("State").ToString()
```

The error is `Conversion from String "Contact Name" to type 'Integer' is not valid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving from The `DataTable` seems wrong in your code.

Use `NameTxt.Text = MyDataTbl.Rows(<Row Number>).Item("<Column Name>")` To retrieve the Data from `DataTable`.

Data Table might contains more than one row so while retrieving the data, it is important to specify the Row Number. After specifying the Row number, we must choose the Column from which we want to retrieve the Data and that is done by `.Item(<Column Number as Integer or Column Name as string>)` method.

Comment: Problem Solved.. Thank You So Much.. This is my first post and has been answered so fast.. So what do I do now?should I upvote you or what..I don`t know how this works.. Is saying thank you enough?